# How to convert all fractions from the form m/n into the form\dfrac{m}{n}?

Tags: amsmath, fractions

My document have many fractions of the form `m/n`. Now I want to convert all fractions from the form m/n into the form \dfrac{m}{n}. [image]
I can't find a way to convert. The unique way is by hand.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ m/n + p/q = 2/3. \]
I want 
\[\dfrac{m}{n} + \dfrac{p}{q} = \dfrac{2}{3}.\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there always exactly one character (letter or numeral) before and after the slash character? Does the slash character occur in text mode too, or only in math mode?

Comment: @Mico Not exactly one.

Comment: @Mico I used Mathematica and Maple. There is always whitespace to set off the elements.

Comment: @Mico I am sory about my question. You can understand simplify   all frac m/n into the form \dfrac{m}{n}.

Comment: Can you use LuaLaTeX, or are you limited to using pdfLaTeX?

Comment: I am using pdfLaTeX.

Comment: With `(a + b)/c`, what is the correct transformation ? `\frac{(a + b)}{c}` or `\frac{a + b}{c}`?

Comment: @PaulGaborit My fractions has unique form a/b, 123/345,...

Comment: why do you want `\dfrac` rather than the more common and more generally useful `\frac` (the output would be the same in this case)

Comment: This is a task for the editor --- find how to do a regular expression replace, and then change ` ([a-zA-Z0-9])+/[a-zA-Z0-9]) ` to ` \dfrac{\1}{\2} ` --- be careful with the withespaces and quoting, but a serious editor should have a kind of "ask for confirmation" for each one of the matches.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. If you are forced to use pdfLaTeX you may be out of luck. Hopefully, though, the answer will still be useful to other readers.

A major issue with infix fraction notation, such as `a/b` and `1/2`, is that by the time TeX has a chance to notice the presence of a `/` symbol in the input stream, the material that's supposed to form the numerator is already gone; backspacing to recover the numerator would be very tedious (or maybe even impossible). A preprocessor-based approach seems more promising. Fortunately, LuaTeX provides the `process_input_buffer` callback, which is very suitable for pre-processing.

The following example code provides a Lua function that performs the infix-to-dfrac conversion. The only syntactic requirement is that characters in the numerator and denominators consist solely of alphabetic characters and arabic numerals. (No parentheses allowed) Whitespace to the immediate left or right of the `/` (slash) symbol is permitted.

Given the replacement of `/` with `\dfrac`, this Lua function should **never** be run on inline-math mode material, let alone text-mode material, lest it play havoc with any `/` characters. The code therefore also provides two LaTeX macros -- `\ReplaceOn` and `\ReplaceOff` -- which activate and deactivate the Lua function. I suggest you insert a `\ReplaceOn` directive at the start of each group of equations that contain infix fractions and a `\ReplaceOff` directive at the end of each such group.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
function sltodf ( s ) -- "slash to dfrac"
  return ( string.gsub ( s , "(%w+)%s-/%s-(%w+)" , "\\dfrac{%1}{%2}" ) )
end
\end{luacode*}
%% TeX-side code
\newcommand\ReplaceOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback (
    "process_input_buffer", sltodf, "sltodf" )}}
\newcommand\ReplaceOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback (
    "process_input_buffer", "sltodf" )}}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\dfrac' macro

\begin{document}
\ReplaceOn
\[ m /n + pq / rs = 1 / 2 - 21/ 32 . \]  % lots of whitespace

\[m/n+pq/rs=1/2-21/32.\] % no whitespace at all

\[ 2a /3b + pq/rs = a / 5 - 61c/41d . \] % mixtures of letters and numerals

\ReplaceOff  % no more infix to frac processing

\[ m /n + pq/rs = 1 / 2 - 21/32 . \]
\end{document}
```

---

---

*Addendum*: To extend the scope of the Lua function to the entire document automatically, it's necessary to perform some tests to check if we're in a display-math environment, and to perform the infix-to-frac conversion only if that's the case. How to do this is shown in the following example. Six display math environments are recognized automatically (in addition to the "basic LaTeX" `\[` and `\]` commands): `equation`, `align`, `alignat`, `flalign`, `gather`, and `multline`. Both the "starred" and "regular" variants of these environments are handled.

The requirements regarding input syntax are fairly mild. Expressions with `\[ ... \]` are permissible, as are all display math environments in which the opening and closing statements, such as `\begin{equation}` or `\end{align}`, are on lines by themselves.

The code below also provides the macros `\ReplaceOff` and `\ReplaceOn`, as it may be necessary to suspend operation of the Lua function "by hand", say, in case of a `verbatim`-like material that contains displaymath code.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for various displayed-equation environments

%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
in_dispmath = false  -- set up a Boolean variable
function sltofr ( s ) -- "slash to frac" 
   -- if we find a '\[ ... \]' line, perform infix fraction replacements
   if string.find ( s , "\\%[.*\\%]" ) then
      return ( string.gsub ( s , "(%w+)%s-/%s-(%w+)" , "\\frac{%1}{%2}" ) )

   -- switch 'in_dispmath' to 'true' if at start of a displaymath env.
   elseif string.find ( s , "\\begin{equation%*?}" ) or
          string.find ( s , "\\begin{align%*?}" ) or
          string.find ( s , "\\begin{alignat%*?}" ) or
          string.find ( s , "\\begin{flalign%*?}" ) or
          string.find ( s , "\\begin{gather%*?}" ) or
          string.find ( s , "\\begin{multline%*?}" ) or
          string.find ( s , "\\%[" ) then
      in_dispmath = true

   -- switch 'in_dispmath' back to 'false' if at end of a displaymath env.
   elseif string.find ( s , "\\end{equation%*?}" ) or
          string.find ( s , "\\end{align%*?}" ) or
          string.find ( s , "\\end{alignat%*?}" ) or
          string.find ( s , "\\end{flalign%*?}" ) or
          string.find ( s , "\\end{gather%*?}" ) or
          string.find ( s , "\\end{multline%*?}" ) or
          string.find ( s , "\\%]" ) then
      in_dispmath = false

   -- if in displaymath mode, replace infix fractions with \frac expressions
   elseif in_dispmath == true then
      return ( string.gsub ( s , "(%w+)%s-/%s-(%w+)" , "\\frac{%1}{%2}" ) )
   end
end
\end{luacode*}

%% TeX-side code
% Assign the Lua function to the 'process_input_buffer' callback 
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback (
    "process_input_buffer", sltofr, "sltofr" )}}

% Macros to enable and disable the Lua function "by hand";
% this may be needed if the document contains verbatim sections
%   that feature displaymath-mode code
\newcommand\ReplaceOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback (
    "process_input_buffer", sltofr, "sltofr" )}}
\newcommand\ReplaceOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback (
    "process_input_buffer", "sltofr" )}}

\begin{document}
\[ 2m /3n + pq / rs = 1 / 2 - 33/ 55 . \]

\[
2m/3n+pq/rs=1/2-33/55.
\] 

\[1/2+1/2=1\]\[1/3+1/3+1/3=1\]
\begin{align*} 
1/2+1/2         &=1\\ 
1/3+1/3 + 1 / 3 &= 1
\end{align*}

When not in display math mode, no processing: ``and/or'', $a/b$, $1/2$

\ReplaceOff  % get ready for some verbatim material
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{align*} 
1/2+1/2         &=1\\ 
1/3+1/3 + 1 / 3 &= 1
\end{align*}
\end{verbatim}

\ReplaceOn % back to 'normal' (replacement) mode
\begin{align*} 
1/2+1/2         &=1\\ 
1/3+1/3 + 1 / 3 &= 1
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I get the text file?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 - Sorry, I don't understand your question. Which text file?

Comment: I am sorry, text file like David Carlisle' answer.

Answer (score 17):

If the supplied file is saved as `f.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ m/n + p/q = 2/3 . \]
I want 
\[\dfrac{m}{n} + \dfrac{p}{q} = \dfrac{2}{3}.\]
\end{document}
```

then

```
sed -e "s@ \([a-zA-Z0-9]\+\)/\([a-zA-Z0-9]\+\) @ \\\\dfrac{\\1}{\\2} @g"  f1.tex  > f2.tex
```

will produce

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ \dfrac{m}{n} + \dfrac{p}{q} = \dfrac{2}{3} . \]
I want 
\[\dfrac{m}{n} + \dfrac{p}{q} = \dfrac{2}{3}.\]
\end{document}
```

`sed` is available by default in unix-like systems (linux, macos, cygwin...) and available from lots of places for windows.

The same regular expression replace could also be done in any text editor if the commandline sed is not wanted.

Comment: Where I put the line `sed -e "s@ \([a-zA-Z0-9]\+\)/\([a-zA-Z0-9]\+\) @ \\\\dfrac{\\1}{\\2} @g"  f1.tex  > f2.tex `?

Comment: @toandhsp that is not a line to put into a file it is a command to type to the commandline to the editor sed. If you don't have sed or prefer to use a graphical editor select regular expression replace and replace `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` by `\\dfrac{\1}{\2} ` which is what the above specifies